# djangorestframework - Boolean field with default value True changes to False

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have, among various other fields, a boolean field like below in my *models.py*:

```
is_searchable = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

When using PUT request to modify either of the fields of the model, value of `is_searchable` changes to `False` even if nothing related to it is specified in the PUT request.

I am using `serializers.ModelSerializer` here. Version of django rest framework - 3.0.1

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to update is_searchable you have to define it as read_only field in your serializer class.

Eg:

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_searchable = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)
```

otherwise, pass the correct value true/false

Comment: I am afraid that's not what I am looking for. User might want to set it to False through the app which API has to abide by.

Comment: In your put request if you don't pass nothing for is_searchable it will be set to false

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I found it has to do with my curl command. You must add `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` .
e.g.

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"is_searchable": true}' http://<your-instance>/<your-api>/
```

Answer (score -2):

You may use **initial**

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_searchable = serializers.BooleanField(initial=True)
```